# GCC rejects a simple-declaration with an enum-base; clang accepts it — which is correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, language-lawyer, c++14

[GCC 4.9.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9e5e3eb78115c91) doesn't compile this snippet, but [clang 3.5.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cebed037dd588dbc) does. Which one is correct?

```
enum F : int { x, y, z};
int F;
enum F:int f = F::x;
```

GCC output :

```
main.cpp:3:12: error: expected ';' or '{' before 'f'
 enum F:int f = F::x;
            ^
main.cpp:3:12: error: expected class-key before 'f'
main.cpp:3:14: error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token
 enum F:int f = F::x;
              ^
main.cpp:3:16: error: 'F' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
 enum F:int f = F::x;
                ^
```

I believe GCC is correct, as a *simple-declaration* (containing the elaborated-type-specifier `enum F`) doesn't allow an *enum-base* (`: int`), but I'd like some confirmation on this.

Comment: Least helpful question title :-S

Comment: What i can say for sure is that `F` is not `enum class` so `F::x` is invalid.

Comment: @GreenScape, You don't need a scoped enum to use the scope resolution operator.

Comment: @KerrekSB The time to write the comment could have been spent on fixing the title.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: You can't fix the whole world :-( ... at least not every day! (But it's cheap to complain about it.)

Comment: Report the bug here: https://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=clang

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.  An *enum-base* like "`: int`" is syntactically allowed only in an *enum-specifier*, which must contain a `{` bracketed `}` list of enumerators, or in an *opaque-enum-declaration*, which must follow the *enum-base* with an immediate semicolon `;`.

Answer (score 18):

I believe gcc is correct. If we look at the grammar rules in [dcl.enum], the type specifier comes in with:

> *enum-base:*
>      `:` *type-specifier-seq*

The tokens that contain an *enum-base* are:

> *enum-specifier:*
>     *enum-head* `{` *enumerator-listopt* `}`
>     *enum-head* `{` *enumerator-list* `,` `}`
>   *enum-head:*
>      *enum-key* *attribute-specifier-seqopt* *identifieropt* *enum-baseopt*
>      *enum-key* *attribute-specifier-seqopt* *nested-name-specifier* *identifier*
>   *enum-baseopt*

and

> *opaque-enum-declaration:*
>      *enum-key* *attribute-specifier-seqopt* *identifier* *enum-baseopt*`;`

This expression:

```
enum F:int f = F::x;
```

Is neither an *enum-specifier* (no `{}`s present) nor an *opaque-enum-declaration* (in which the type-specifier would be followed immediately by a `;`). Since it's not in the C++ grammar, it's not a valid expression.